# Add abline to facet_zoom in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a data set that looks like this

```
data <- data.frame(x = log(runif(100, min = 1, max = 10)), 
                   y = log(runif(100,min = 1, max = 10)))
```

When I plot using the code below I get an error (`Error in scale_index[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`)

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_zoom(x = x >2 & x < 3, y = y >2 & y < 3)+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color="black", linetype="dashed", size=0.5)
```

Ploting without the abline it works fine, but I really want to add this abline (identity line) without using some image edition efterwards.

[image]

What I would like is to have this:
[image]

I also wouldn't mind to have the line showing up in the main plot (out of the facet_zoom).

This is the error message I get (I'm using ggforce 0.3.3):
[image]

Comment: Your code worked for me. I don't get that error. It has a line.

Comment: Same here. Also the main plot has the line.

Comment: Worked "on my computer" too.

Comment: Here as well using `ggforce_0.3.3` and `ggplot2_3.3.3`

Comment: Ok. That was weird. I was using ggfoce_0.3.3 and ggplot2_3.3.4 and wasn't working. I updated ggplot to 3.3.5 and now it works. Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

aparently was a compatibility problem. I was using ggplot2 v3.3.4. Updating it to v3.3.5 solved the issue.